# Buy specific SKUs get 10% of on all other products

Tags: magento2.4, discount

I am working in Magento 2.4.4

I am trying to set a Cart Price Rule where I say "Buy specific SKUs and get 10% discount on all the rest of products"

Like "Buy X Get Y - Percent Discount".

Is there any possibility to set this up without any extension?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Go to Stores > Attribute > Product

Find attribute "sku". Goto storefront properties > Set to Yes.

Now Goto - Marketing > Cart Price Rules > Add New Rule

Go to Conditions > Press + button and Select - Product Attribute Combination

Then : Inside this, select + button again (inside one).

Now Select "Sku" from the list . and press the three dots and fill the all skus.

And in Actions >  Apply > Percentage of Product Price Discount

Discount Amount : 10

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions.
Select "SKU" from the list and Fill all the skus, you want to apply the rule to.

Fill the other necessary field and Save
[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear @Jasvir, 

thank you for explaining.

Problem here is, that this then works for all mentioned SKUs with 15% discount even if purchased seperately or only one of those.

What I want to achieve is:

Buy SKU 1 and only if one buys SKU 1 then 15% discount are given for other products per SKU 2, SKU 3 etc.

Like "Buy X Get Y - Percent Discount".

Comment: Please check the updated answer (screenshot)