# Cart Price Rule

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I am working in Magento 2.4.5

I am trying to set a Cart Price Rule where I say "Buy specific X SKU and Y SKU get 10% discount on"

Is there any possibility to set this up without any extension?

Best regards

Comment: Please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356367/buy-specific-skus-get-10-of-on-all-other-products

Comment: Yes, implementation this work for me

Answer (score 0):

First Go to Stores > Attribute > Product

Find attribute "sku". Goto storefront properties > Set to Yes.

Now Goto - Marketing > Cart Price Rules > Add New Rule

Go to Conditions > Press + button and Select - Product Attribute Combination

Then : Inside this, select + button again (inside one).

Now Select "Sku" from the list . and press the three dots and fill the all skus.

And in Actions > Apply > Percentage of Product Price Discount

Discount Amount : 10

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions. Select "SKU" from the list and Fill all the skus, you want to apply the rule to.

Fill the other necessary field and Save

[image]

[image]